# Use old explorer search on Windows 7

Tags: windows-7, file-filter

Is there any way to enable the old Windows XP explorer search on Windows 7? Since most of time I am only doing file/folder name search and using the advanced filter (file size/date modified/etc) a lot.

Comment: If I remember correctly, in Win Vista search, there's an option to use traditional search. However, that has been took out in Windows 7.

Comment: @ Stan, No way to do what you want. Use an alternative search software.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Not sure of any direct built-in way to enable the old-style search on Windows 7. However I did spot something called [FileSearchEx](http://goffconcepts.com/products/filesearchex/) which may be in the right direction:

[image: Screenshot]

> [FileSearchEX](http://goffconcepts.com/products/filesearchex/) is for persons who want
>   extremely fast no-nonsense file
>   searching capabilities offered from a
>   clean and intuitive application
>   interface. In addition to the current
>   offering advanced features are planned
>   that will not interfere with design
>   goals.
>
> - Users don't need to learn a new file search utility. XP style search.
> - Much lower system requirements than indexing search offerings.
> - Support for millions of found items for advanced scenarios.
> - Unicode support with internationalized installs planned.
> - Large environment easy installation options.

I checked the site and it looks like it's free for personal use.

There's another rather more functional application from NirSoft called [SearchMyFiles](http://www.nirsoft.net/utils/search_my_files.html) which provides a lot of options to search for your files and folders.

[image: Screenshot]

> [SearchMyFiles](http://www.nirsoft.net/utils/search_my_files.html) is an alternative to the
>   standard "Search For Files And
>   Folders" module of Windows. It allows
>   you to easily search files in your
>   system by wildcard, by last
>   modified/created/last accessed time,
>   by file attributes, by file content
>   (text or binary search), and by the
>   file size. SearchMyFiles allows you to
>   make a very accurate search that
>   cannot be done with Windows search.
>   For Example: You can search all files
>   created in the last 10 minutes with
>   size between 500 and 700 bytes.

Comment: There's also Everything Desktop Search (http://www.voidtools.com/) which supports (some) regular expressions in the search field. I use it mostly because it's so damned fast, but the regexes come in handy too.

Comment: @ Amazed. This should be an Answer.

Comment: @Gareth, Nirsoft's SearchMyFiles doesn't seem to be able to search for filenames only....